# how to get the vlaue from the from the dataframe that is mention in the list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

```
  books=  ['When The Storm Breaks', 'When The Bough Breaks (Alex Delaware Novels (Paperback))', 'Storm Front (The Dresden Files, Book 1)', 'The Fellowship Of The Ring (The Lord Of The Rings, Part 1)', 'The Return Of The King (The Lord Of The Rings, Part 3)', 'The Sign Of The Beaver', 'The Fly On The Wall', 'The Cat In The Hat', 'The Member Of The Wedding']
```

this is my list , so i m trying to get the list item image from a dataframe so i have tried this code:

```
def get_image(books):
    img=[]
    data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/suhel/Desktop/book recommendation/file.csv')
    for i in range(len(books)):
       w=data.loc[data['title']==books[i],'Image']
       img.append(w) 
    return img
```

but it only return only one image link , rest are like this below:

```
    [Series([], Name: Image, dtype: object), Series([], Name: Image, dtype: object), 360    http://images.amazon.com/images/P/0451457811.0...
Name: Image, dtype: object, Series([], Name: Image, dtype: object), Series([], Name: Image, dtype: object), Series([], Name: Image, dtype: object), Series([], Name: Image, dtype: object), Series([], Name: Image, dtype: object), Series([], Name: Image, dtype: object)]
```

is there any way to get all the listed image link from the dataframe without index object or dtype

Answer (score 0):

Use isin

```
result = df[df['title'].isin(books)]['Image']
```

Comment: i tried by its only shows one image link  360    http://images.amazon.com/images/P/0451457811.0...
Name: Image, dtype: object

Comment: See if you can paste the data frame itself which we can copy and execute. Then we can get the root of the problem. Also post expected output of that dataframe